# Android Get OTG USB/External SD CARD Storage devices and their paths

Tags: java, android, usb-otg

I'm using the following code to get the list of all external storage devices either SDCard or USB connected via OTG

```
  List<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
    File directory = new File("/storage");

    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
```

It reads sdcard in all devices but the USB gets detected in some

What should i use?

Answer (score 0):

There are no filesystem paths that you can use on Android 4.4+, except those that are returned by `getExternalFilesDirs()`, `getExternalCacheDirs()`, and `getExternalMediaDirs()` (all plural, all on `Context`).

Ideally, you should be using the Storage Access Framework (e.g., `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`), as that provides the user with the greatest flexibility. However, you are no longer working with files and a filesystem, but rather with `Uri` values, reminiscent of working with Web services.